# Fix rails installation / openssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I seem to have completely messed up my rails installation on Mac Catalina. I was working on a project which was running on the server just fine -> I then made the mistake of updating something, which I don't remember what it was now. Now, no matter what I do all I get is the following:

[image]

PLEASE HELP! I have tried various other suggestions found on SO or other blogs and nothing is working.

Comment: Sorry, we [can't accept images of code, data or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

try to install the:

```
xcode-select --install
```